# Current password can't be blank even when password is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise, updates

I'm trying to update user information, however, whenever I entered the current password and click update i got this message `Current password can't be blank`.

I did an update to the devise edit form a bit, by adding the `<nav>` bar, but I don't think it is the issue. I haven't made any changes to the default devise controller.

This is my edit form:

```
<% if vendor_signed_in? %>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Discount Now", edit_vendor_registration_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" %>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <%= link_to "Home", edit_vendor_registration_path %> </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>Signed in as <%= current_vendor.name %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "log out", destroy_vendor_session_path,:method => :delete, id: "nav-login-button", type: "button", class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn"%></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<body>
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :discount_information %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :discount_info, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
</body>
<%else %>
 <% link_to "sign up", new_vendor_session_path%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have a problem with a open single quote and I believe this is the issue. Notice that after the single quote in the word **don't** at the line of **:password** field the colors of the text change because from this point on everything is being taken as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think current_password parameter is not permitted, please check your console logs. It will show unpermitted parameter.
Try to permit it via devise registration controller or in your application controller in **configure_permitted_parameters** method. Hope it will work.